# Upgrade fail from 14.04 LTS to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, google-chrome

I am trying to upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 14.10.  Using the automatic update it failed at the "Setting Up New Software Channels" step.  The line in the log file in /var/log/dist-update/ showing the failure is below:

```
2015-05-20 17:28:44,010 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate

2015-05-20 17:28:44,011 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'

2015-05-20 17:28:44,011 DEBUG plugins for condition 'utopicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'

2015-05-20 17:28:44,011 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_trustyPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'

2015-05-20 17:29:02,898 DEBUG Foreign: google-chrome-stable

2015-05-20 17:29:02,898 DEBUG Obsolete: gs-cjk-resource language-support-en language-support-writing-en linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic

2015-05-20 17:29:02,901 DEBUG updateSourcesList()

2015-05-20 17:29:03,254 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList()

2015-05-20 17:29:03,264 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,265 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,266 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,266 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,267 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,267 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,268 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,269 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,269 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,270 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,270 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,271 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,271 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,272 DEBUG entry 'deb //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,273 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,273 DEBUG entry 'deb-src //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,274 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,274 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,275 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,276 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,276 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,277 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,277 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,278 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,278 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,279 DEBUG entry 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,280 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,280 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,281 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,281 DEBUG entry 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,282 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,282 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,283 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,284 DEBUG entry 'deb ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,284 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,285 DEBUG entry 'deb-src ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,285 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe main multiverse restricted'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,286 DEBUG entry 'deb ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed universe main multiverse restricted' updated to new dist

2015-05-20 17:29:03,286 DEBUG examining: 'deb ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'

2015-05-20 17:29:03,300 DEBUG entry '# deb ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to utopic' was disabled (unknown mirror)

2015-05-20 17:29:07,974 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)

2015-05-20 17:30:21,916 DEBUG openCache()

2015-05-20 17:30:21,917 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 

2015-05-20 17:30:32,502 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 47187

2015-05-20 17:30:32,503 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')

2015-05-20 17:33:24,486 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'

2015-05-20 17:33:24,487 DEBUG abort called

2015-05-20 17:33:24,491 DEBUG openCache()

2015-05-20 17:33:35,942 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 45865

2015-05-20 17:33:35,961 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

Here is the output of cat /etc/apt/source.list.

```
>      # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100429)]/ lucid main restricted
>         # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
>         # newer versions of the distribution.
>         
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
>         
>         ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
>         ## distribution.
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
>         
>         ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
>         ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
>         ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
>         
>         ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
>         ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
>         ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
>         ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
>         ## security team.
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
>         deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
>         
>         ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
>         ## repository.
>         ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
>         ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
>         ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
>         ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
>         ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
>         # deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>         # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
>         # deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ # disabled on upgrade to trusty
>         
>         ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
>         ## 'partner' repository.
>         ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
>         ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
>         # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
>         # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
>         
>         deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
>         deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
>         deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
>         deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
>         deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
>         deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
>         deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
```

Here is the output of ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d file.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 176 May 20 17:29 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 176 Apr 29 20:46 google-chrome.list.save
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and the content of the folder `ls -og /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: I got a notice for an 14.04 update.  I accepted it.  I can't remember the exact date but it was around 15 September.  I thought it was odd since 14.04 was not supported.  I thought I would see if the upgrade to 14.10 would work.  Low and behold, it did.  I have been able to upgrade to 15.10.  I have two computers with the same mother board which behaved the same way.  I concluded there was an issue in Ubuntu which was resolved and allowed me to upgrade.